# Error while JDK version is changed

Tags: java, android

I have created a project on jdk 1.6 and android Rev. 20 . Now I have installed 1.7 for few features, but it is not accepting. We have to import `sun.audio` package in java 1.7 which we intend to use in android. But it is giving me errors. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you put some part of your error code.

Comment: Please post the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the same [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439057/eclipse-imported-a-project-and-eclipse-is-giving-me-wrong-override-method-ann) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578441/can-the-android-sdk-work-with-jdk-1-7)

And also sun package should not used [Check Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html)

Solution for your question is

Right Click on project -> Properties -> Java Compiler -> Check the "Enable Project Specific settings" -> change compiler version to 1.6

Answer (score 0):

sadly , android still does not support java 1.7 . you have to find a workaround and not use this package .

for audio , you have a lot of built in classes and also third party classes .

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

click on **System requirements**